# Solr british and american spelling

Tags: solr

Search for 'globali**z**ation' only returns search results for 'globalization' but doesn't include any results for 'globali**s**ation' and vice versa.

I'm looking
into solr.HunspellStemFilterFactory filter (available in Solr 3.5).

`<filter class="solr.HunspellStemFilterFactory" dictionary="en_GB.dic,en_US.dic" affix="en_GB.aff,en_US.aff" ignoreCase="true" />`

Before upgrading from Solr 3.4 to 3.6.1 I was wondering if Hunspell filter is the way to go?

Thanks

Comment: English stemming should be good even with Snowball. Have you tried it?

Comment: I ran into this same issue and used the `SynonymFilterFactory` with much success.  The dictionary I ended up using is called VarCon and can be found here: http://wordlist.aspell.net/varcon/.  It took some processing to convert that dictionary into a format suitable for SOLR but not too bad.  I now have 16k+ synonyms...including globalization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If stemming doesn't solve this for you, you could always use a [SynonymFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters/#solr.SynonymFilterFactory) in order to normalize both spellings into one, I guess a dictionary containing US/UK spelling variations wouldn't be hard to come by.